# como puedo hacer que un bot de discord responda a los comandos de otro bot (python)

Tags: python, discord.py

importacion de los modulos

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands as cmd
```

declaracion de metodos y objeto

```
bot = cmd.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")
```

comandos con funcion

```
@bot.command()
async def math(ctx,op):
    ret = eval(op)
    await ctx.send(ret)
```

comando de prueba

```
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!hi")
```

evento ejecutado al iniciar el bot

```
#mensaje de salida en la consola de comandos que verifica la correcta ejecucion del bot en cuestion del producto Discord de la empresa Discord Inc.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("my bot is ready")**
```

ejecucion del bot

```
#ejecutando el bot
bot.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes enlazar una función con el evento `on_message`, que ocurre cada vez que alguien envía un mensaje. Asegúrate de tener los intents y permisos necesarios para poder leer y enviar mensajes.

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Esto está para evitar que el bot se responda a si mismo.
        # Si piensas hacer que el bot solo responda a usuarios/bots especificos, puedes sacar esta sección.
        if(message.author.id == bot.id):
            return
    
        # Si el id del autor del mensaje no es el id del bot al que se debe responder, sale de la función.
        # donde dice 12345 en realidad va la id del bot al que se debe responder.
        if(message.author.id != 12345):
            return
    
        # Tu código aquí

        # obtenemos el canal donde se envió el mensaje
        # esto nos permitirá enviar un mensaje al mismo canal donde se recibió el mensaje.
        channel = message.channel

        await channel.send("aquí va el mensaje que quieras")
```

#### Advertencia

Discord.py está descontinuado oficialmente desde el 28 de agosto del 2021 :c
Te recomiendo pasarte a otro modulo o lenguaje de programación. Mientras buscaba el mensaje que dejó el creador sobre la discontinuación, encontré un modulo que parece plantearse como la continuación de discord.py: https://pythonrepo.com/repo/nextcord-nextcord

---

#### Edit

Según el OP mi idea hace que los demás comandos no se puedan ejecutar. Según [una respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/12913664) que dirige a una sección de [la documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) de discord.py, parece que al enlazar una nueva función al evento `on_message`, se reemplaza una función encargada de procesar los comandos del bot.

Para solucionar esto hay dos caminos (esto según la documentación)

**1- bot.process_commands**

Puedes añadir al final de la función esta linea `await bot.process_commands(message)` que procesa los comandos del bot.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Tu código aquí
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

**2- Listener**

Puedes colocar la función en un [listener](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.listen). Parece que en este caso particular puedes llamar a la funcion como quieras:

```
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def nombre_funcion(message):
    # tu código aquí
```

Comment: si pongo esto en mi codigo, los demas comandos no se ejecutan cuando los llamo

Comment: @Lizard el `return` si puede estar vacío, si no se especifica algún de valor de retorno (o un propio `return`) hay un `return` implícito y siempre retorna `None`

Comment: @Lizard Aunque lo que dijo Christian es cierto, te agradesco lo del async, se me olvidó xD

Comment: no lo sabia, pero me daba un error de sintaxis, aun asi, sigue sin responder a los comandos

Comment: Ya encontré una solución. Ahora lo agrego a mi respuesta!

Comment: gracias dannte S.

Comment: @lizard no puedo probarlo, pero creo que esto es la solución, mira el edit :D

Comment: gracias, ya me funciono, te lo agradezco

Comment: oye tengo otra pregunta diferente, pero queria preguntarte a ti, como puedo hacer que el bot envie un mensaje al server sin necesidad de que alguien llame al comando?

Comment: Hay dos motivos por los que preferiria que preguntes eso en una nueva pregunta en SO. 1-la respuesta que de podria ser util para otros, por lo que es mejor que sea visible para todos. 2-alguien que sabe mas que yo podria responderte.

Comment: Igualmente, sobre tu duda depende lo que quieras hacer. Quieres mandar un mensaje cada x tiempo, a una hora determinada, tras un evento especifico?